# Is my file input causing my "instance of 'std::logic_error'"?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am attempting to do some file input to read in aspects of rooms into variables which will then be made into objects (a room is an object, and the passageways north, east, south, and west are objects).

The file I am reading from looks like this:

```
2 3
The Start,-,+,red_key,-,axe blue_key
The Landing,-,+,-,+,
Master Bedroom,-,-,-,+,red_key
The Kitchen,red_key,+,-,-,
The Hall,-,+,-,+,
The Exit!,-,+,-,+,
```

The rooms will be placed into a 2d array. I have read in the amount of rows and columns from the file correctly, but things get ugly towards the end of each line for the rooms. Here is what I have attempted to do:

```
char discard = ',';
string roomName;

string nPassage;
string ePassage;
string sPassage;
string wPassage;

char lastChar;

string listOfItems;

for(int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++)
{
    roomName.clear();
    listOfItems.clear();

    for(int j = 0; j < this->columns; j++)
    {
       getline(cinMaze, roomName, discard); cout << roomName << endl;
       getline(cinMaze, nPassage, discard); cout << nPassage << endl;
       getline(cinMaze, ePassage, discard); cout << ePassage << endl;
       getline(cinMaze, sPassage, discard); cout << sPassage << endl;
       getline(cinMaze, wPassage, discard); cout << wPassage << endl;
       cinMaze >> lastChar; cout << "\"" << lastChar << "\"";

       room roomInMaze(roomName, createPassageWay(nPassage), createPassageWay(ePassage), createPassageWay(sPassage), createPassageWay(wPassage));
       theMaze[i][j] = roomInMaze;

       if (lastChar != '\n')
       {
           cinMaze.putback(lastChar);

           getline(cinMaze, listOfItems);
           theMaze[i][j].addItem(listOfItems);
       }
    }
}
```

The words after the last comma on some lines of the file are items needed for doors which a player will loot when he/she enters the room. I thought that the last comma was disposed of by the way I wrote the program and then I'd be able to test for \n and either move on or out back any char so I can read the list of items needed.

All of the cout statements are there for testing purposes... This is what I am getting when I test this:

```
The Start
-
+
red_key
-
"a"The Landing
-
+
-
+
"M"The Kitchen
red_key
+
-
-
"T"The Exit!
-
+
-
+
"T"The Exit!
-
+
-
+
"T"The Exit!
-
+
-
+
```

What am I not understanding about file I\O or something else?

Comment: On what line does your compiler say the `logic_error` occurs? Please read [example] and try to cut this down to the absolute minimum example (that means start from scratch) that duplicates your error. This is extra work on your part. That's true. But this isn't supposed to be a free debugging service. It makes the question much easier to answer for us, and helps you understand the problem better. We're volunteers. Help us help you.

Comment: Quoting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error): *No standard library components throw this exception directly*. This exception should be thrown as one of the derived classes or you throw it yourself (or a library you use throws it).

Comment: Could you share the part related with the `std::logic_error` ?